# Datapump library

Tags: oracle, datapump

I'm developing a java program and with it, I want to be able to import and export oracle datapump.

Do you know any library that i could use which will enable me to do so?

Another option is to do it with the console, but I'm not very keen on doing so.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is a PL/SQL package which wraps the Data Pump functionality.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_datpmp.htm).